# Collectionview Maximum space between cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

In my application i use UICollectionView for listing of product. Requirement is to set height of cell conditionally. I use following code for it.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
        if (indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 6 || indexPath.row == 7 || indexPath.row == 10 || indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width/2)-4, 300.0);
        }

        return CGSizeMake((collectionView.frame.size.width/2)-4, 250.0);
}
```

by, this code completely set height of cell but horizontal cell not set properly like image. i want remove extra space between vertical cell. I set min spacing for cell and line are 8pixel from storyboard's edges.

Thank you in advance.[image]

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest

Comment: @VirajPadsala i need for objective-c and without constrain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solve the problem by wonderful library [Link](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout) and very easy to implement.

Comment: Hi, @Pramod Tapaniya Congratulation for 400+ reputation